# How can I call OutputDebugString from a windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, debugger

The context:  I have a batch file that runs periodically as a scheduled task.  While I can debug this with `echo` statements by invoking it directly from a Cmd.exe command prompt window, If I could call `OutputDebugString` from the batch file, I could presumably monitor the scheduled task with *DebugView++* or similar.

Is this possible?  I guess I could do it by calling a 3-line Python program, but I was wondering if there was a means of doing it with less impact.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this batch-Python hybrid:

File ODS.BAT

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & python -x "%~f0" %* & EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL!
  
#============================================================================

import sys, win32api, shlex

#============================================================================
def ODS (S):
    win32api.OutputDebugString ("Batch: " + S)
    return
#============================================================================
 
cmdline = " ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv[1:]))
ODS  (cmdline)
exit (0)
```

Performance is not stellar however - on an i7-4700MQ at 2.4GHz the call overhead is around 120 mS.

```
6993.558805 2021/01/03 00:57:01.217 78472   python.exe  Batch: first call
6993.710674 2021/01/03 00:57:01.369 77512   python.exe  Batch: second call
6993.846577 2021/01/03 00:57:01.505 12548   python.exe  Batch: 3
6993.991280 2021/01/03 00:57:01.649 18540   python.exe  Batch: 4
6994.139500 2021/01/03 00:57:01.797 41688   python.exe  Batch: 5
6994.279880 2021/01/03 00:57:01.938 86844   python.exe  Batch: 6
6994.420741 2021/01/03 00:57:02.079 73856   python.exe  Batch: 7
6994.566055 2021/01/03 00:57:02.225 86064   python.exe  Batch: 8
6994.735341 2021/01/03 00:57:02.394 69644   python.exe  Batch: 9
6994.888729 2021/01/03 00:57:02.547 46524   python.exe  Batch: 10
6995.212918 2021/01/03 00:57:02.871 88856   python.exe  Batch: 12
```

Just for curiosity's sake I then tried this:

File ODSEcho.bat

```
@echo %Date% %Time% Batch: %*
@exit /b %ErrorLevel%
```

Overhead for this was ~7mS!

```
2021-01-03  0:57:02.89 Batch: first call
2021-01-03  0:57:02.90 Batch: second call
2021-01-03  0:57:02.90 Batch: 3
2021-01-03  0:57:02.91 Batch: 4
2021-01-03  0:57:02.91 Batch: 5
2021-01-03  0:57:02.92 Batch: 6
2021-01-03  0:57:02.93 Batch: 7
2021-01-03  0:57:02.94 Batch: 8
2021-01-03  0:57:02.94 Batch: 9
2021-01-03  0:57:02.95 Batch: 10
```

(go figure...).  I'm assuming that the Python interpreter loading is the culprit.

(Although the pure batch solution is much faster, it does not send its output stream to the resident debugger, which is the aim of this exercise).

If I get time I will try others (VBS, Powershell).